# asp.net mvc 3 regular expression returning encoded html?

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
public static string MakeAnchor(string text) 
{
    string pattern = @"((?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*)";
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
    var anchor = r.Replace(text, "<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$1</a>");
    return anchor;
}
```

This method returns `&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;http://google.com/&lt;/a&gt;` if I pass it some text containing http://google.com/

instead of `&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com/&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;http://google.com/&lt;/a&gt;`

I'm using razor views with MVC 3. I'm stumped. Is there some sort of new view encoding in MVC 3 that I'm unaware of?

Comment: the method doesn't actually show that it's returning the encoded string in the debugger, it's just that the view writes it that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you use @: (in Razor) or <%: (in the WebForm View Engine) the text will be automatically html encoded. Try @= or <%=

Answer (score 1):

Make your method return an [`IHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) to indicate to the framework that your output is already encoded.

The simplest implementation of that is `return new HtmlString(anchor);`

`IHtmlString` is implemented in .NET 4, so if you're in .NET 3.5, you'll have to use the `@=` or `<%=` syntax (as @[Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271507/asp-net-mvc-3-regular-expression-returning-encoded-html/4271532#4271532) mentions) to avoid encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog post (http://www.akngo.com/) that shows how to "wrap" Htmlstring for convenience sake. Usage is RawView.SomeString

> I have been using the Razor engine for
>   a few days now, and I am liking it a
>   lot. I noticed one big problem right
>   from the start, all strings are HTML
>   encoded. For our uses, this becomes
>   quite an annoying “feature” when we
>   deal with JSON strings. For example,
>   given a simple JSON string, ["1", "2",
>   "3", "4"]
>
> The actual HTML encoded output of this
>   became, ["1", "2",
>   "3", "4"]
>
> The quotes have been escaped, which is
>   not the desired output. If we need to
>   send HTML back out, or XML, we would
>   have to then individually escape
>   those. Overall, I find this quite
>   annoying as we would have to wrap it
>   inside of an HtmlString as shown in
>   this StackOverflow post.
>
> In our scenario, we are generating
>   JSON/XML from C#, so most of the time,
>   our serialized data is inside of the
>   ViewModel. Which would result in us
>   doing things like, @(new
>   HtmlString(View.Foo)) @(new
>   HtmlString(View.Bar))
>
> As you can see, this can become quite
>   cumbersome. So I decided to
>   plagiarized part of MVC to create a
>   RawView. In the end, the usage will
>   be, @RawView.Foo @RawView.Bar
>
> I also went ahead to allow the usage
>   of the index operator as well in case
>   there’s a need to loop over it with a
>   list of keys. // Assuming we have Foo,
>   Bar, and Baz in our ViewModel @{
>       List keys = new List { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };
>       foreach (var key in keys) {
>           @RawView[key]
>       } }
>
> To achieve this, I would need to
>   duplicate DynamicViewDataDictionary.
>   Naturally, I named it
>   DynamicRawViewDataDictionary, public
>   class DynamicRawViewDataDictionary :
>   DynamicObject
>       {
>           private readonly Func viewThunk;
>           public DynamicRawViewDataDictionary(Func
>   viewThunk)
>           {
>               this.viewThunk = viewThunk;
>           }
>
> ```
>     private ViewDataDictionary ViewData
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             ViewDataDictionary viewData = this.viewThunk();
>             return viewData;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public object this[string key]
>     {
>         set { setData(key, value); }
>         get { return getData(key); }
>     }
>
>     public override IEnumerable<string>
> ```
>
> GetDynamicMemberNames()
>           {
>               return ViewData.Keys;
>           }
>
> ```
>     public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder,
> ```
>
> out object result)
>           {
>               result = getData(binder.Name);
>               return true;
>           }
>
> ```
>     public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder,
> ```
>
> object value)
>           {
>               setData(binder.Name, value);
>               return true;
>           }
>
> ```
>     private object getData(string key)
>     {
>         object value = ViewData[key];
>         if (value is string)
>         {
>             return new HtmlString(value.ToString());
>         }
>
>         return value;
>     }
>
>     private void setData(string key, object value)
>     {
>         ViewData[key] = value;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The reason for the duplication is
>   because the DynamicViewDataDictionary
>   is an internal sealed class. There was
>   no way I could get around this
>   restriction other than copying and
>   pasting. The obvious change I made to
>   this class is the getData method. I
>   checked to see if the object is a
>   string, if it is, I wrapped it with an
>   HtmlString().
>
> Now I need to use this inside of a
>   WebViewPage, since all views , I have
>   to have a customized version of a
>   WebViewPage as well. Good thing that
>   MS didn’t make this class internal
>   sealed, so I can easily inherit from
>   it. I needed to make a generic and a
>   non-generic version, I just plopped
>   both of this inside of one file.
>   public abstract class
>   CustomWebViewPage :
>   WebViewPage
>       {
>           private DynamicRawViewDataDictionary _rawData;
>           public dynamic RawView
>           {
>               get
>               {
>                   if (_rawData == null)
>                   {
>                       _rawData = new DynamicRawViewDataDictionary(() =>
>   ViewData);
>                   }
>                   return _rawData;
>               }
>           }
>       }
>
> ```
> public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
> {
>     private DynamicRawViewDataDictionary _rawData;
>     public dynamic RawView
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (_rawData == null)
>             {
>                 _rawData = new DynamicRawViewDataDictionary(() =>
> ```
>
> ViewData);
>                   }
>                   return _rawData;
>               }
>           }
>       }
>
> For the final touch to actually make
>   this work, at the top of the cshtml
>   file, you should have something like,
>   @inherits
>   Namespace.To.CustomWebViewPage
>
> //or @inherits
>   Namespace.To.CustomWebViewPage
>
> Now that the cshtml file inherits from
>   the new CustomWebViewPage, it should
>   have access to RawView, which will
>   wrap all strings with an HtmlString.
>
> Once you have this in place, you’ll
>   still need to make sure that all of
>   your new views inherits from
>   CustomWebViewPage. I highly recommend
>   using custom code templates in your
>   MVC project to generate the view. This
>   will help with automating a lot of the
>   mundane tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Htmlstring is the answer.

```
@(new HtmlString(SomeString))
```